# Low pass filter calculation for H-bridge output

Tags: motor, simulation, h-bridge, low-pass

I'm controlling a motor through an H-bridge, and want to low-pass filter the output of the bridge before the signal going into the motor. The purpose is to remove high-frequency noise that might disturb radio signals (EMC). The cutoff frequency should be at 25 kHz.

The H-bridge is controlled by 2 LTC4446 gate drivers, with a 20 kHz PWM generated from a microcontroller.

I've tried using the TI Application Report for SLAA701A–October 2016–Revised November 2016, LC Filter Design, but have had massive troubles with it. I can design a filter with a quality factor of 0.7068 and with almost the correct cutoff frequency, but the transfer functions show a very off-looking filter with a high gain before the cutoff frequency is reached.

Furthermore, the inductor that I should use for that filter would be around 600 uH, which is way too high.

However, I've managed to design a filter that works just perfect, even though it shouldn't if I refer to any calculations...
The problem is that I have to describe what I did and why for my report, and "It was lucky" isn't a suitable explanation.

Can any1 help me explain why this works? Refer me to any literature or formulas that can explain it?

Thanks in advance!
[image: Circuit diagram]
[image: Simulation]

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want your cutoff frequency _higher_ than the PWM frequency? That is very unusual.

Comment: Why don't you do what is most commonly used, which is a "snubber" network in parallel with the motor. So no filter, the H-bridge connects directly to the motor. Between the motor's contacts connect a 47 nF capacitor in series with a 100 ohm resistor. What you want to do is **short** the RF frequencies generated by the motor. That's what the R + C network will do. Your circuit will not do that as well as 100 uF and 22 uF capacitors have a high impedance at RF frequencies.

Comment: Perhaps your filter designer assumes a linear system - an H-bridge signal source may not be regarded as "linear"?

Comment: @pipe is it? I thought it should lie just above since you want the frequency components from the signal that you recieve

Comment: @glen_geek I see. How did u come to the conclusion of those specific values for the capacitor and the resistor for the snubber network?

Comment: Pretty sure that your "weird" filter is because you don't measure the right nodes, but you've omitted all the information about why you think the original filter is wrong, so I don't think it's possible to answer this constructively. You should focus on the first problem instead.

Comment: @HelenaFærch regarding the cutoff frequency being above the PWM, the motor can't possibly respond to a 20kHz signal.  It only "cares" about the average voltage between its terminals.  That's because of the very large inductance of the windings, and the huge angular moment of inertia of the rotor.  So you wouldn't have to have the filter above the PWM frequency, though Bimpelrekkie's suggestion of a snubber may be a good solution as well.  Also, your simulation doesn't include parasitics like ESL and ESR, so it may not reflect real-world performance.

Comment: +1 on what pipe said. Something is strange and I sense an XY problem.

Comment: Your filter needs to cut-off way lower than your PWM frequency. Take the advice and show your original circuit. Nobody should make guesses at this.

Comment: I'm curious to know more about how to design the snubber circuit @Bimpelrekkie suggested, specifically the specific values for the resistor and capacitor. 
However, I feel like the comments, although well-meaning, have gotten off track. 
The filter I designed using the application note from TI was wrong since it got a giant gain peak just before the cut-off frequency. The bodeplot was generated in Maple and not simulated, so ideal components was used.

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if I could get help with the problem I posted about: explaining why the filter I have designed and showed in the LTSpice snippet works as seen from the plot I have supplied. I would prefer formulas or other literature, but links, videos, and your own explanation is appreciated as well. The filter might not be ideal and other methods might have been preferred, but since this is for a school project with a limited time frame, I am not able to redo it by now.

Comment: *how to design the snubber circuit* Not all circuits are "designed" (using formulas etc). Often circuits are used that are **known to work**. So I **know** that a 22uF cap. isn't good at RF and that a 47 nF cap. will be much better (check datasheets of capacitors).

Comment: *It would be greatly appreciated if I could get help with the problem* No one here will help you with that because **you** made a strange design choice (LC filter for EMC reasons) while experienced engineers would not solve that like you propose. To many of us your solution simply does not make sense.

Comment: Experienced engineers would, I used the TI application note which uses it for that reason too. My specific problem is that I have a large inductive load which is not handled in the design guides I've seen. Good for you if you can create circuits based on "I know it works, that should be good enough", but that is not sufficient for a report. I need to be able to explain my component choices. The switching frequency of the H-bridge will be increased to acommendate for the filter cut-off frequency of the low-pass filter. Suggesting solutions that cannot be explained is not a good solution.